What is wrong with using the $H^1_0$ inner product here?
This question is a problem I am toying with.
Consider the Poisson equation,
$$-\Delta u =f \ \text{in} \ \Omega \times (0,\infty).$$
$$u=0 \ \text{on} \ \partial \Omega \times (0,\infty)$$
Suppose the domain $\Omega = \Omega_1 \cup \Omega_2.$ And $u(x,t)$ is defined piecewise across this domain, for example: \begin{equation}
u := \{
    \begin{array}{lr}
        u_1, & \text{if } x \in \Omega_1 \\
        u_2, & \text{if } x \in \Omega_2
    \end{array}
\end{equation}
(Similarly for $f :=(f_1,f_2).$)
If now, I scale the Poisson equation on the second domain $\Omega_2$ by some $\alpha>0$, to get this new system:
$$-\Delta u_1 =f_1 \ \text{in} \ \Omega_1 \times (0,\infty),$$
$$-\alpha \Delta u_2 = \alpha f_2 \ \text{in} \ \Omega_2 \times (0,\infty).$$
$$u=0 \ \text{on} \ \partial \Omega \times (0,\infty)$$.
Could I still use the Riesz representation theorem by applying the $H^1_0$ inner product on the whole $\Omega$? Or would I be forced to redefine my inner product? What if the coefficients were continuous?
(I believe I would be forced to redefine my inner product to apply Riesz, however, I could still just use Lax Milgram. But the question of continuous coefficients is one I don't know how to answer)

All that are required to apply these theorems for existence and uniqueness are that the coefficient function is $L^\infty(\Omega)$ and $f\in L^2(\Omega)$, neither of which require any continuity in any dimension (see sections 6.1 and 6.2 of Evans for example). In this case, you can continue to consider the $H^1_0(\Omega)$ inner product over the entire domain. The piecewise definition of $u$ also may not even lie in $H^1_0(\Omega)$ if $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}$.
